# Django Models: Attribute name assignment for names that differ only by a number

Tags: python, django

I have this model (whose purpose is to hold data):

```
class UserPhraseDatum(models.Model):
    result_from = models.ForeignKey(Results, related_name="data")
    phrase = models.ForeignKey(Sound)
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=4)
    snr = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    m_energy_1 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField() 
    m_energy_2 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    m_energy_3 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    m_energy_4 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    m_energy_5 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    m_energy_6 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    m_energy_7 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    u_energy_1 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    u_energy_2 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    u_energy_3 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    u_energy_4 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    u_energy_5 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    u_energy_6 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    u_energy_7 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

Eventually the info in these instances will be analyzed in `R`, and possibly spat out to a CSV. There will *always* be 6 entries for `m_energy` and 6 entries for `u_energy`. Is there a nicer way to assign these?

Comment: What database backend are you using? Postgres has support for arrays, others do not. Also, do you need to index or search those fields?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Right now, just SQLite, but I'll be moving to MySQL. I do not need to index them, and, while it would be nice to search them (eventually), it's not a necessity. (In fact, this whole question is not a necessity! ;) I'm just seeing if there's a way to eliminate a few lines)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using postgreSQL, you should refer to `ArrayField` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/).

Your use case would be, instead of:

```
u_energy_* = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

You can do:

```
u_energies = ArrayField(size=6, models.PositiveSmallIntegerField())
```

If you really can't migrate over to postgres, then I suggest using a `TextField` and parsing your data when you perform transactions. This can be handled in a class that extends `models.TextField`, but this way is definitely more adhoc and prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a reverse `ForeignKey` relation. You need to create to additional Models:

```
class m_energy(models.Model):
     content_field = '''some content'''
     UserPhraseDatum = models.ForeignKey('UserPhraseDatum', related_name = 'm_energies')
```

and `u_energy` is the same.

In your queries u can take `m_energy` in this way:

```
var = UserPhraseDatum.objects.filter(m_energies__content_field )
```